# What is difference between new or instance directly about QPropertyAnimation?

Tags: qt

**the code as follow doesn't create the animation... But if the QPropertyAnimation is a new instance , then it can.. Why? what is the difference ? Thank you...**

```
        QRect orgRect = this->geometry();
        QRect endRect = btExpand ? QRect(*ptNotePadPot, COLLAPSE_SIZE) : 
                                   QRect(*ptNotePadPot, EXPAND_SIZE);
     /*
        QPropertyAnimation* amt = new QPropertyAnimation(this, "geometry", this);
        amt->setDuration(10000);
        amt->setStartValue(orgRect);
        amt->setEndValue(endRect);
        amt->start();
    */
        QPropertyAnimation amt(this, "geometry", this);
        amt.setDuration(10000);
        amt.setStartValue(orgRect);
        amt.setEndValue(endRect);
        amt.start();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After it starts, QProperyAnimation will create its own timer and run outside your main thread.

```
QPropertyAnimation amt(this, "geometry", this);
```

it will be destroyed after run pointer exit your function scope.

otherwise if u use

```
QPropertyAnimation* amt = new QPropertyAnimation(this, "geometry", this);
```

you will create one animation  object in the memory to work and its pointed by amt pointer.
the pointer will be deleted after run pointer exit your function scope, not the QPropertyAnimation object.

but it will be a zombie in the memmory if you not delete it.

the best way is, use a class variable for QPropertyAnimation pointer. so you can delete the object in the pointer after program closed or when ever u want.

i hope it helps..
sory for my bad english.

Comment: firstly, Thank you for helping me..According to your means, it will create a thread ?

Comment: your welcome Tu_JianWu.. yes.. it will create a new sub thread from your QObject like QTimer for an example.

Comment: Oh、I see. That is what confused me long before.

Comment: Just to be clear, it does not create a new thread.  The animation's timer will run as part of the event loop, on the main thread.

Comment: @DanMilburn yup.. youre right.. thats what i mean.. work in the same thread but at the background.. what should i call it.. for now i call it sub thread.. ;p

Answer (score 0):

A better way to solve this without memory leak is to call the start() method like this:

```
animation->start(QAbstractAnimation::DeleteWhenStopped);
```